# Failing to check Firebase child (null PathString)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to call values on my database, but I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try and query my database.

This is my code

```
mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mCurrentUserId);
mUserRef.keepSynced(true);
mUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        selected_group = dataSnapshot.child("group").getValue().toString();
        String position = dataSnapshot.child("position").getValue().toString();

        if (position.equals("head of toddlers"))
        {
            my_group = "Toddlers";

        }
        else if (position.equals("head of juniors"))

        {
            my_group = "Juniors";

        }
         else if (position.equals("head of seniors"))
        {
            my_group = "Seniors";
        }
        else if (position.equals("head of ambassadors"))

        {
            my_group = "Ambassadors";
        }




    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});


    rcvListMessage = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.announcements_list);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mMessageReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Requests").child(my_group);  // <--- this is where i'm getting the error
```

this  is my log cat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
   at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
   at org.maninresponsibility.www.womaninresponsibility.HodMembers.onCreate(HodMembers.java:113)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
```

The database I'm querying has Requests then a child group which groups the users on their respective groups. What am I supposed to do in order for me to be able to use child(my_group) to check for values in my database. Thank you in advance, PS. for answers I would appreciate an explanation on the cause of the error and how I should approach such cases for future references.

this is my database structure:

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: Kindly give your database structure.

Comment: i have updated my question please check the image i attached for the database structure

Comment: @PradyumanDixit

Comment: Based on the code you shared, the `mCurrentUserId` is `null` in `child(mCurrentUserId)`. I recommend running the code in a debugger, and verify that `mCurrentUserId` is initialized when you try to attach a listener..

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Please check my answer i think it's clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `mCurrentUserId` as the error you've shown in logcat says that can't pass `null` in `child()`.

If it is, then your `mCurrentUserId` is not correctly retrieved. You can try to retrieve it as follows:

```java
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mCurrentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

However a more certain and precise answer can be given if you attach your database structure.

**Edit:**
From your database structure I can't see any field named `Users`. So the problem is that you've not correctly referenced to your database.

You should try replacing your code with this code:

```java
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests").child("Toddlers").child(mCurrentUserId);

mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  String selected_group = dataSnapshot.child("group").getValue().toString();
    String position = dataSnapshot.child("position").getValue().toString();

    if (position.equals("head of toddlers"))
    {
        my_group = "Toddlers";

    }
    else if (position.equals("head of juniors"))

    {
        my_group = "Juniors";

    }
     else if (position.equals("head of seniors"))
    {
        my_group = "Seniors";
    }
    else if (position.equals("head of ambassadors"))

    {
        my_group = "Ambassadors";
    }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

**Edit2:**
After seeing your full code, and the database, the problem is that you're not referencing correctly. You can replace the part of your code with this:

```java
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Head of departments").child("head of toddlers");
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot != null)

            {
                mDatabase.child("Requests").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot != null)
                        {
                            mMessageReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Head of departments").child(my_department).child("Requests");
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I have added code exactly as you'd want, but I don't see a node named `position` in the image of your database. So, I hope it is present.

Comment: mCurrentUserId is fine i entered it just like how you're saying the problem is my_group line

Comment: @Siphamandla I can't see `Users` node at all in your attached part of database. SO maybe that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think `my_group` is getting null that's why this error occurred. I have seen your database structure.If you want retrieve this type of structured data then, your code should be like :

```
 mMessageReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests").child("Toddlers"); 
    //and then
    mMessageReference..addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String value = dataSnapshot1.child("group").getValue().toString();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

And i think Toddlers is also a child so you need to insert in your database path.
    `my_group` is not a key in your database. your key is `group` that why its getting  null error. Actually this is not best way to retrieve data you need create one model class for that then its easy to retrieve.

```
Read this documentation for more information:
```

[How to retrieve data in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: Thank you @Sasuke Uchiha let me change my code but this look correct

Comment: check my answer